# Can you electrostatically charge materials with X-rays?

Tags: electrostatics, condensed-matter, radiation, photoelectric-effect, x-rays

I am wondering if by making use of the [photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) someone using for example X-rays radiation could electrostatically charge positively a dielectric like glass [[1]](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1722919) and make it therefore attract a relative negative charged object like a copper foil?

This could have some interesting applications in industrial fine particles filtration [[2]](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00022470.1975.10470071). Does this kind of method would have any merits in an industrial or other application? For example, cases where other more conventional methods of filtration are not applicable and would profit from applying such method?

Furthermore, if this method can attract dielectrics using X-rays, can it used for cleaning oxidation and dirt from metals without using chemicals?

Comment: This is demonstrated here at this time stamp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpoBZeOCcZo&t=1336s where a bulb when feed with KHz and KV power is clearly attracting a copper plate. I believe that the bulb operating at this high frequency and volts of electricity is actually radiating X-rays that charges the glass of the bulb.

Comment: The man in the video also says that it has an opposite, repulsing effect on humans. This is more likely due to the fact that the man approaching the bulb with his hand in the video, gets irradiated with X-rays and becomes the same amount positively charged with the glass and therefore repelled.

Comment: Found also this related paper: https://doi.org/10.1080/00022470.1975.10470071

Comment: Also this article about photoelectric effect on Borosilicate Glass with UV radiation https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1722919

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course. X-rays are light at the end of the day. It is like solar panels. You might not use pure glass, but it would work. And to answer your other question, you would be able to pull metals out of dirt and other substances because of the properties of the charge on the glass plate. Some industrial applications would include pulling harmful and heavy metals out of grain silos while processing the grain.

Comment: Great! I think this would be a much more environmental friendly filtration solution.

Comment: Yes, I think this would be. There are also many more uses than the one that I have listed here. Also thanks for your feedback.